# Anaconda 3 Navigator Not Opening

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 3 on my computer and it will not open the navigator or let me run any of the programs, such as Jupyter Notebooks or Spyder. When I click on the Navigator app it briefly opens two black screens and then closes and then doesn't do anything. If I try to run it from the command prompt it gives me the following error.

```
>anaconda-navigator
```

WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in 
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 37, in 
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.analytics import GATracker
  File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\analytics.py", line 44, in 
    from anaconda_navigator.external.UniversalAnalytics import Tracker
  File "C:\Users\micha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\external\UniversalAnalytics\Tracker.py", line 28, in 
    from six.moves.urllib.request import (HTTPSHandler, Request, build_opener,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'six.moves.urllib.request' (unknown location)

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall many times and I attempted to manually install an SSL package because some people suggested this worked for them.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have also attempted to update anaconda as well and it does not work because it appears it is not letting the system make external requests.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I just had to move some files within anaconda3 installation folder from one path to another.

Navigate to %ANACONDA_HOME%\Library\bin, there you will find the files listed below

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libcrypto-1_1-x64.pdb
libssl-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.pdb
So, just move them to this path: %ANACONDA_HOME%\DLLs

Give it a try one more time and you will be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that there is an issue with the `urllib3` package. According to a source, the error occurs when Anaconda Navigator tries to use the latest version of urllib3 installed via pip, which is not compatible with the version required by Anaconda Navigator.

The solution is to uninstall the requests and urllib3 packages that were installed via pip, so that Anaconda Navigator can use its own version of these packages located in its site-packages directory. You can do this by running the following commands:

```
pip uninstall requests 
pip uninstall urllib3
```

---

After running these commands, try opening Anaconda Navigator again to see if the issue is resolved. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem today, **solved it by doing the following:**

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the way OP has to fix? And are you able to explain why?