# Unable to start Anaconda Navigator

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

My system is on windows 10. I recently deleted files in the temporary folder. Now I am not able to start anaconda navigator and I get the output as shown

[image: Output]
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc8i2.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it: 
Maybe dosen't solve every problem, but for me it worked, and for quite many it also worked: `pip install pyqt5`

[github: **Windows - Anaconda Navigator Not Opening #1581**](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1581)

[**same solution here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10)

[**Anaconda 3 Navigator Not Opening**](https://superuser.com/questions/1451789/anaconda-3-navigator-not-opening)

Hope it solves itself somehow.
have a good day on you.

NOTE: I'm new here, sorry if my english isn't the best, or any of my answears / questions. Just trying to help.